# How do Data Raven and Chum interact?

Tags: android-netrunner

[Chum](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/01075) deals 3 damage if the next encountered ICE doesn't have all its subroutines broken. [Data Raven](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/01088) gives the runner the option to either take a tag, or end the run when encountered before proceeding to its subroutine.

If the runner takes the option to end the run after encountering the Data Raven, do they still take the 3 net damage?

(This would also apply to a TollBooth the runner couldn't pay 3C towards)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [FAQ](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CEAQFjAB&url=http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/android-netrunner/support/FAQ/Android-Netrunner%2520FAQ.pdf&ei=CLPtUOaKHdSY0QW8v4GQDA&usg=AFQjCNFW0BmF6c_nzjPXla5E0Ditf_suSw&bvm=bv.1357316858,d.d2k):

> Does the Runner take damage if he jacks out after encountering a Chum
> and not breaking its subroutine?
>
> No. The Runner has not encountered
> another piece of ice, and  so the subroutine on Chum has no effect.

Data Raven's "tag or quit" ability triggers *when the runner encounters* the ICE, though.  So by that point the runner MUST now break all the subroutines or pay the Chum penalty... jacking out of the run now won't save them.

Comment: How about if you use Femme Fatale to bypass the DataRaven? You still encountered it to trigger the Femme Fatale's bypass ability(which happens at the same time as the tag or quit, but you can bypass first as its your turn and avoid the tag), but didn't break any subroutines. Does this mean that the Chum will trigger when the second ice is bypassed with Femme?

Comment: Again in the FAQ, it says "any subroutines on the ice bypassed are not broken".  So bypassing subroutines with Femme Fatale again won't save you from Chum's effect!

Comment: Looks like putting a Chum in front of any ICE which gets Femme Fatale'd would be a good move then :)

Comment: @thesunneversets - Do you have a link to the FAQ you've quoted?

Comment: Good point Mr I&C... have edited the answer with a download link to the PDF, which will hopefully be a useful resource!